# Android resources - failure getting entry

Tags: java, android, android-studio, resources

I rewrote my app to a new project to have the code tidier and also use pre-defined fullscreen activity from Android Studio. The app was working perfectly fine (at least past the point when it crashes now). The app populates a gridview from an SQLite database via custom CursorAdaper, and the error seems to be there, more specifically - it looks like a problem with the layout that should be populated (A linear view of fixed dimensions, 2 children - ImageView and TextView.

Ichecked the resource from the first line in R.java and this value is assigned to the name of the layout that should be inflated by the cursor. Any idea how to fix it?

```
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f040031 (t=3 e=49) (error -75)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.madry.mtg, PID: 21183
              android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f040031
                  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:198)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2114)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1115)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:424)
                  at com.madry.mtg.MyCursorAdapter.newView(MyCursorAdapter.java:33)
                  at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:285)
                  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2433)
                  at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1065)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19785)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1117)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:642)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19785)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19785)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19785)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:393)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19785)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19785)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19785)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:690)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19785)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2275)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1362)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1611)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1250)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6311)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6217)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

The MyCursorAdapter class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static com.madry.mtg.MyDBHandler.COLUMN_COLOUR;
import static com.madry.mtg.MyDBHandler.COLUMN_POWER;
import static com.madry.mtg.MyDBHandler.COLUMN_TAP;
import static com.madry.mtg.MyDBHandler.COLUMN_TS;

public class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter{



private LayoutInflater cursorInflater;

public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context, c, flags);
    cursorInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(
            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return cursorInflater.inflate(R.layout.token, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    Log.d("adapter", "zaczelo wiazac");
    Symbol symbol = new Symbol();
    String sciezka = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_COLOUR));
    symbol.setPath(sciezka);

    int path = symbol.getPath();

    ImageView clr = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    clr.setImageResource(path);

    int tap = cursor.getInt((cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_TAP)));
    if (tap == 0){
        view.setRotation(0);
    } else {
        view.setRotation(20);
    }


    TextView stats = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    String p = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_POWER))+
            "/" + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_TS));
    stats.setText(p);
   }

}
```

Comment: @PedroValério just added

Comment: Do you have a "token,xml" layout in the base 'res\layout' folder ? The exception indicates that it can't load that layout.